# Mapstruct interface implementation is not created on the same package

Tags: java, gradle, mapstruct

I am using mapstruct in Gradle project, after building the project the implementation of the mapper interface is created in, `build\generated\sources\annotationProcessor\java\main`
So I have to manually copy this file and paste under the mapper package. As I know this should be done by mapstruct itself.
So my question is how to do it??[Following this Github code](https://github.com/tkgregory/gradle-annotation-processor-example)